# What is the most humane way to edit text files inside 'windowsservercore' Docker image?

Tags: docker, text-editors, docker-for-windows

Sometimes it becomes handy when you can make few config file changes *inside the container*, and then running some commands to try things before hardcoding all things into `Dockerfile`. Is the ancient *MS-DOS editor*, `edit` really the way to go in Windows-ServerCore (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore), or are there some humane solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution, but what I do is [install chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), and then run `choco install nano`, then `nano myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Define volume(s) for the relevant files and use a regular text editor outisde the container. And when the files are OK, you don't even need to salvage them from the container for the Dockerfile build, since they will be in the host filesystem.

Also, it is sometimes useful to keep the config outside of the container so that you can start variants by just binding different volumes to the instances.